# Using Lookup in MS Access Forms

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a MS Access Form that has Student ID,

This is ok, I can see student ID as it should be

What I want is to display Student Name instead of Student ID

I used ***SELECT StID, StName From Students*** in "Row Source" 
"Row Source Type" = Table/Query
"Bound Column" = 1

I could not find any property where I can decide the Display Column

Help is much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Go to the "FORMAT" tab of the Form Properties Dialog Window (the same one you used to set the **Row Source** and **Row Source Type** properties)
2. You'll see two fields (**Column Count** and **Column Widths**)
3. Set **Column Count** to 2.
4. Set **Column Widths** to 0";1"

This works in Access 2007. Any version later then 2007 should also work.

By setting the column count to '2' you're displaying the StudentId and the Name. Then by setting StudentId column width to '0' you are hiding the column.

When you switch to Form View you will see the **Student Names**, but the value stored underneath is really the **StudentId**. Neat trick.

Hope this helps.